# Kentico and TFS build server setup

Tags: kentico

Does anyone have an recommendation on set up for TFS as a build server? While i can publish from VS, when code is pulled from TFS, the build fails. Seems all the references are broken.

Do we need to do a base install first? I'm passing this information on to the build manager.

Comment: What errors are you getting? I have some experience with setting up TFS as a build server and it's quite easy and if you need something special you can just hook up a custom PowerShell script...

Comment: When the code was pulled from TFS, there were build errors. I duplicated it on my local machine, which is when i noticed the references had lost, well, their references. My acutel workspace will build and publish fine, so i think for the TFS build process, it may need a Kentico install.

Comment: Would be nice to see which exact references were missing. That would help resolve your issue.

Comment: TFS build server does not need Kentico install. You may need to configure it so it restores all NuGet packages before build.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, check if DLLs in bin folder are checked in with the rest of source code. Also make sure build server restores all NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

i moved all dlls from bin folder to SharedBinaries folder inside the root, than created references.
than you need to set up TFSBuild.proj